# Unable to send FCM Push Notification

Tags: c#, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have integrated google-services.json into my mobile application. I am trying to send notification on actual device using https://testfcm.com/.

This was working till yesterday and have stopped working from today morning for me.

Does it have something to do with [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/93522#issuecomment-1600272887)?

But seems this changes is going to be in place from next year.

Comment: If your device is an Android 13, notification permission should be enabled to receive notifications.